# SSIS Rollback Package

Tags: ssis

I have several data flow tasks in my package that depend on other data flow tasks.  For testing reasons I want to run the entire package and then roll it back after it completes.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all the changes in a transaction and then abort it.

[How To Use Transactions in SQL Server Integration Services SSIS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no other activity that you need to persist (assumed from the reference to testing) then a [database snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx) can be useful here.

There's obviously a tipping point around the volume of change whereby a regular full backup could be faster if you're churning a large percentage of the database. But, as the creation of the snapshot is instantaneous (the mechanism uses a [sparse file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175823%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)) and the regular backup route requires you to create the backup first, snapshot is usually the winner for dev/test activity.

Note that [reverting from a database snapshot shrinks the transaction log to 0.5MB](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/bug-reverting-from-a-database-snapshot-shrinks-the-transaction-log-to-0-5mb/) due to a rather nasty bug, so you'll need to re-size your transaction log appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a backup, and then restore from that backup on error or as the last step.  The backup and restore could be steps in a job, with the SSIS package being a step between.  That way, when you've got everything else worked out the way you want, the SSIS package can be used to make and keep the data changes you want.